# C# Register a dll driver programmatically while runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

> Sorry if it's a duplicate question, but I couldn't find an answer.

I'm writing a program for store scales. The driver of the scales is available in **.dll** format. I'm using the program by referring to the driver in this **.dll**. Now I register **.dll** via CMD. So I need to register **.dll** while runtime or installing application. But I couldn’t set it up either by reference or by code.
Now I'm registering it up as follows.

```
c: [Enter]
cd \RongtaScales [Enter]
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe  file.dll [Enter]
```

It works this way, but customers can’t always register it that way. I need to register it along with the program.
I tried the following:

```
try
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"E:\rtscaledrv.dll");
            RegistrationServices regAsm = new RegistrationServices();
            bool bResult = regAsm.RegisterAssembly(asm, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
            MessageBox.Show("Installed: '"+ bResult.ToString() + "'");
        }
        catch (Exception exs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: '"+ exs.ToString() +"'");
            //throw;
        }
```

This returned an error as follows:

[image]

If I try to add via Referenceses it returns the following error:

[image]

My question is, how can I register a .dll together while the program is running or installing? I can't find the exact answer from google right now.
Thanks!

**UPDATED**
If I try with batch file it also doesn't work:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "RegSvr32=%SystemRoot%\System32\regsvr32.exe"
set "RegAsm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe"
if not exist "%RegAsm%" set             "RegAsm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe"
if not exist "%RegAsm%" set     "RegAsm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\RegAsm.exe"
rem Make note of any files which cause an exception to be thrown.
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir a-d /b *.dll *.ocx') do "%RegSvr32%" /s "%%~fA"     && echo %%~nA SVR Registered || "%RegAsm%" /nologo /silent "%%~fA" 2>nul && echo     %%~nA ASM Registered || echo %%~nA Skipped
endlocal
@pause  /b 0
```

It returned:

```
rtscaledrv Skipped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a batch file?

Comment: Yes, but it didn’t help.

Comment: I mean you can put those 3 lines (As you said it is working when you do it manually) into a bat file and run it as administrator.

Comment: @Farshad Can you give an example? For some reason it didn’t work for me. After that, is there no other way to do it through the bat?

Comment: What did you get when you did that? @minordestroyer

Comment: Nothing, opened and closed but not registering.

Comment: put "pause" at last line to see if any thing has happened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224145/discussion-between-farshad-and-minordestroyer).